# recursively add to python dictionary from tuple

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dictionary

I'm attempting to take the tuple ('a', 'b', 'c') and create a layered dictionary like this:
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}.  I'm using recursion to do this.  When I print out the dictionary after each stage of my script (many prints simply for debugging purposes) it shows that the dictionary is being created correctly, but then it is taken apart and left incorrect.  The dictionary I'm left with is {'c': {}}.  I must be doing something improper with the recursion part.  Any help will be much appreciate.  Here is my code:

def incr_dict(dct, tpl):

```
if len(tpl) == 0:
    dct = dct
    print(dct)
    print('1')
else:
    dct = {tpl[-1]:dct}
    print(dct)
    print('2')
    incr_dict(dct, tpl[0:-1])

print(dct)
print('3')
return dct
```

dct = {}
tpl = ('a', 'b', 'c')

dct=incr_dict(dct, tpl)

print(dct)
print('4')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *ALMOST* there!! Change the `incr_dict(dct, tpl[0:-1])` line to read `return incr_dict(dct, tpl[0:-1])`. I believe that will fix the problem.

When using recursion, it is important to return the recursive call -- otherwise the 'higher levels' of the recursion can't make use of the new information. By returning the recursion, the execution will continue to recurse until the terminating condition is met, and then the computed values will begin to be returned up the chain until they are finally returned from the first invocation of the function.

---

The final code should look as follows:

```
def incr_dict(dct, tpl):
  if len(tpl) == 0:
      dct = dct
  else:
      dct = {tpl[-1]:dct}
      return incr_dict(dct, tpl[0:-1])

  return dct

dct = {} 
tpl = ('a', 'b', 'c')

dct=incr_dict(dct, tpl)

print(dct)
```

I removed some of the debugging statements for clarity.

Comment: Much appreciated, works wonderfully.  I knew it was a small error I couldn't catch because I'd been staring at it too long (this is what happens when you stop coding for the first month of summer...).